# hiddenfield have to change on every onclick

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Am new to asp.net,c#.
Am having dynamic boxes(each companies),it will create at the run time.Now On each click of the box my hidden field should give the respected id.If am clicking that box I can get the company id from database,now if the company id is 5 my hidden field should get 5,if it is 7 my hidden field should give 7.Am using asp.net control hidden field(necessary to use in sql datasource).I can asp.net control hiddenfield values only in c#.
How can I change the hidden field values in c# with javascript for every click

How to achieve this using c# and javascript coding?please help me out

Comment: Why does the hidden value need to change? What are you using it for? If you're using the hidden ID as the next ID in your database you should consider generating the IDs automatically on the DB end.

Comment: Am displaying pop up(display database values with repeators,sqldatasource)based on the value of hidden field..If the value of hidden field is 5 i can get the db values with id 5.I given <asp:control parameter> as hidden field.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly:

When you dynamically add your textboxes to the page add an onclick event handler.

```
int id = 1; // You'd have access to this.
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Attributes.Add("onClick", string.Format("javascript:someFunction({0})", id));
// add other stuff.
form1.Controls.Add(tb);
```

Then have a javascript function to set the value of your hidden field:

```
function someFunction(id) {
    var hiddenField = document.getElementById("hdnField");
    hiddenField.value = id;
}
```

Note that I set the clientIdMode of the hidden field to Static and the id to "hdnField". If you don't have the option setting the clientIdMode (pre .Net 4) you'll have to <%= hdnField.ClientID %> (off the top of my head). You'd also probably want to check in the javascript that you're definitely passing in a number.